# Cannot build older version of Geant4 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc, cmake, ubuntu-18.04, geant4

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed in my machine, and I'm trying to install older versions of Geant4 (more specifically 10.01 and 9.6) due to compatibility with existent tools I've built before.

I noticed that, in Ubuntu 18.04, the oldest version of Geant4 that can be built without errors is the 10.02 and above. The older ones (10.01 and 9.6) always return errors in the "make" step, as shown below:

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/physics_lists/CMakeFiles/G4physicslists.dir/lists/src/HadronPhysicsShielding.cc.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/physics_lists/CMakeFiles/G4physicslists.dir/lists/src/MaxTimeCuts.cc.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/physics_lists/CMakeFiles/G4physicslists.dir/lists/src/MinEkineCuts.cc.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/physics_lists/CMakeFiles/G4physicslists.dir/lists/src/QBBC.cc.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/physics_lists/CMakeFiles/G4physicslists.dir/lists/src/SpecialCuts.cc.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/physics_lists/CMakeFiles/G4physicslists.dir/lists/src/G4PhysListUtil.cc.o
[ 95%] Linking CXX shared library …/…/outputs/library/Linux-g++/libG4physicslists.so
[ 95%] Built target G4physicslists
Makefile:151: recipe for target ‘all’ failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My wild guess is incompatibility with cmake and/or gcc versions (?). As an example, in Ubuntu 16.04 I can build those versions without errors, but I want to leave the installation of an older OS as the last resource. Same goes for VM - the Monte Carlo simulations are quite demanding in terms of processing, and performing it in a VM is, from my experience, somewhat frustrating.

My question are:

- Is it possible to have multiple versions of cmake and/or gcc installed? If yes, is there any smart way of managing multiple versions?
- Could the errors be from another issue, instead of incompatibility with cmake and/or gcc versions?

I really appreciate some help, as I'm stuck with these installation issues.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Message `recipe for target ‘all’ failed` is like "**something** goes wrong". Actual error message is somewhere above in the log. Also, make sure that you run *non-parallel* `make` (without `-j` option).

Comment: Thanks for your message. I tried building up again the application in a non-parallel way (without the -j option), but get the same errors. The actual errors are quite extensive.